# QT Creator accessing pointers to objects

Tags: c++, qt

Very new to QT but basically I have a class called object and on my GUI is a one button and one text browser. Now in my class object I have one private QString variable called name and its constructor assigns a value (QString) to the variable called name . The object class has one function called QString getName() const; which returns the name:

```cpp
class object{

private:

    QString name;
public:

    object(QString name);

    QString getName()const;
};
```

Now in QT in my mainwindow.h file I put

```
public: 
    object *o;
```

and then in the constructor :

```
object o2("Name");

o = &o2;
```

Now I want to call the function void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() and all this function will do is set the text in the text browser to the name variable in my object (which would be "Name" btw) so inside the function I put ui->Console->setText(o->getName()); console being the name of my text browser- when i run the code and click the button its saying that Ive referenced memory and giving an error. Keep in mind I moved ui->Console->setText(o->getName()); to the constructor and it worked perfectly (obviously didnt work when the button was clicked but the text was put in the text browser) so what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `o = &o2;` BAD. When `o2` goes out of scope, it is destroyed, thus any reference to it (from `o` for example) is Undefined.

Comment: Though you're using Qt, that's not really related here. The question is about plain C++ usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer (`o`) outlives the object that it points to (`o2`). One way to fix it is by allocating new memory for the object:

```
o = new object("Name");
```

And then you'll need to remember to delete that memory later.